# Regular expressions: Remove all spaces between Quotation marks

Tags: regex

I am struggling for a long time to Find all spaces within proper quotes in order to replace them later.

```
<Field Name="Client Co de" Id="0" ParentId="-1" RepeatedCount="-1" RepeatedBy="-1"/>
```

I am willing to find All spaces within Attribute Name value Name="**Client Security Code**". In this case, it should find 2 spaces. between (t_S) and (y_C)

Could any of you explain it to me how to find it?
Thank you very much

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: not any language, using just pure regular expressions.
This is for manual Replacement in Notepad++ using regular expressions. I am doing my best to reach test that expressions in regex101.com but your opinion is wrong, it collects all spaces, not mine desired one. I have exported css file with thousands of lines with attributes Name with spaces and I want just get rid of those ones. (Other attributes does NOT contain any space". For example bold Name="([^"]+) bold will find the content of Name attribute, all I need more is to extend this command to find spaces inside this substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this for a `regex` to get rid of whitespace:

```
var pattern = /\s*/g;
```

I'm not sure of the language you are using but you can also do some sort of `.replace()` method.

`string.replace(pattern, "");`

Comment: This is for manual Replacement in Notepad++ using regular expressions. I am doing my best to reach test that expressions in https://regex101.com/  but your opinion is wrong, it collects all spaces, not mine desired one.
I have exported css file with thousands of lines with attributes Name with spaces and I want just get rid of those ones. (Other attributes does NOT contain any space". For example **bold** Name="([^"]+) **bold** will find the content of Name attribute, all I need more is to extend this command to find spaces inside this substring.

Comment: Yea, so when you are selecting each "Name" attribute, it will be of type `string`.  Since it is a `string`, you can call `.replace()` on the value of the "Name" attribute.  You can use `.replace(/\s*/g, "");`, which will get rid of all white space including tabs or use `.replace(" ", "");` which will get rid of only spaces.  So however you are getting access to your attribute, you can add this to the `string`. @MatoušKlugar